# POST method Http 500 error

Tags: java

**EDITED**

My project has Java on serverside.BackboneJS,requireJS etc on clientside
I'm trying Get method return 200.But POST method return 500 error.

My Java Model class

```
    private int travelID;//nullable false
    private Date travelStart;
    private String Location;//nullable false
    private String projectCode;//nullable false
    private float travelCost;
    private String travelPurpose;
```

TravelDTO

```
    public class TravelDTO implements Serializable {

    public TravelDTO convert(Travel model) {
        this.setTravelID(model.getTravelID());
        this.setTravelCost(model.getTravelCost());
        this.setTravelStart(model.getTravelStart());
        this.setTravelEnd(model.getTravelEnd());
        this.setLocation(model.getLocation());
        this.setTravelPurpose(model.getTravelPurpose());
       this.setProjectCode(model.getProjectCode());
       this.setUser(new UserDTO().convert(model.getUser()));
        return this;
    }
        private int travelID;

       private String projectCode;

        private Date travelStart;

        private Date travelEnd;

        private String Location;

        private float travelCost;

        private UserDTO user;

        private String travelPurpose;

    public UserDTO getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserDTO user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getProjectCode() {
        return projectCode;
    }

    public void setProjectCode(String projectCode) {
        this.projectCode = projectCode;
    }

    public int getTravelID() {
            return travelID;
        }

        public void setTravelID(int travelID) {
            this.travelID = travelID;
        }

        public Date getTravelStart() {
            return travelStart;
        }

        public void setTravelStart(Date travelStart) {
            this.travelStart = travelStart;
        }

        public Date getTravelEnd() {
            return travelEnd;
        }

        public void setTravelEnd(Date travelEnd) {
            this.travelEnd = travelEnd;
        }

        public String getLocation() {
            return Location;
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            Location = location;
        }

        public float getTravelCost() {
            return travelCost;
        }

        public void setTravelCost(float travelCost) {
            this.travelCost = travelCost;
        }

        public String getTravelPurpose() {
            return travelPurpose;
        }

        public void setTravelPurpose(String travelPurpose) {
            this.travelPurpose = travelPurpose;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TravelDTO travelDTO = (TravelDTO) o;

        return travelID == travelDTO.travelID;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return travelID;
    }
}
```

Part of my error in IntellijIdea

```
    Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Location" (Class com.travelSystem.dto.TravelDTO), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@275735; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.travelSystem.dto.TravelDTO["Location"])
```

My request data

Location:"Kayseri"

projectCode:"15"

travelEnd:"8.12.2016"

travelPurpose:"asdf"

travelStart:"1.1.2"

Comment: Error 500 is because you have an error syntax. Please see your code again and sure you don't have an error, like a ";" or an end of bracket, etc.

Comment: I'm sure no syntax error for my code.The post edited @FernandoUrban

Answer (score 0):

A 500 server error indicates that the server crashed (generally through an unhandled exception) while attempting to process your request.

This could happen either because of a bug on the server side (e.g. attempting to connect to a database that is down), or a bug in your request which the server did not expect (e.g. you passed something as an integer when the server was expecting a string).

Arguably both scenarios are bugs on server side, as it be able to gracefully recover from either scenario (e.g. by returning a 503 Service Unavailable in the first scenario, and a 400 Bad Request in the second scenario)

Comment: I added error on Intellij Idea.May be solution for this 500 error.I looked but didn't find the solution